# Kendo Grid Excel Export limitation

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there a limitation or maximum number of records that can be returned to the excel export functionality of the Kendo Grid?

Sometimes I get a Network error in the browser but investigating this leads to nothing specific about the Kendo platform.

Ive set AllPages = true and there are aboyt 30000 records to return via web odat api controllers in an asp.net web app.

Cheers
Michael

Comment: It really depends on your system resources: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/excel-export#known-limitations.  I'd only use the built-in export as a quick, temporary solution until you can implement a server-side solution using the Document Processing Library, which will at least eliminate any client-side resource bottleneck.  30000 is a lot of rows to jam into the browser/javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There are no Kendo UI - specific limitations, but there are limitations related to data serialization and browser memory.

Setting `AllPages` to `true` will make the Kendo UI DataSource request all items in a single request. Make sure your server implementation is able to serialize them, and the web server is able to send them.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/excel-export#excel-export-of-all-data